# on puppy linux, how to manage power settings

Tags: power-management, laptop, puppy-linux

I'm new to using Puppy Linux, and I'm not able to find a way to manage power settings. The laptop stops working everytime I close and re-open the lid so I want to disable that function from doing anything.